# CSS not properly affecting HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site and am having a hard time getting the CSS to affect the HTML the way I expect. Here is the page I'm working on: [www.lindseybakermedia.com/design/shop-local-weekly/](http://www.lindseybakermedia.com/design/shop-local-weekly/). The part giving me problems is the list of deals. First of all, I've added padding to each div, but the text seems to be expanding out of their respective divs for some reason. Second, I've used `:last-child` to keep the bottom border off the last div, but it doesn't seem to be working either. I've been using Firebug to figure out what's going on, but really have no idea. Any help would be much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<section id="homeDealsList">
   <div id="dealsContent">
      <div id="expirationHeader">
         <!-- EXPIRATION DATE GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY -->
         <p>These deals expire on <span id="expiration">06/03/15</span>.</p>
      </div>
      <!-- ONE DIV GENERATED WITH CONTENT FOR EVERY DEAL -->
      <div class="deal">
         <a href="businessProfile.php?recordID=27" title="logo"><img src="_logos/1418244707.jpg" alt="Business Logo" class="businessLogo" /></a>
         <div class="businessContactInfo">
            <!-- LINK TO BUSINESS PROFILE -->   
            <h4><a href="businessProfile.php?recordID=27">New York Dogs</a></h4>
            <ul>
               <li class="ChamberTitle-A">Chamber Member</li>
               <li>12145 NW Grand Ave</li>
               <li>Any Town, Arizona 85335</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="dealDescription">
            <p>"The Works" Only $2 This Week!</p>
            <a href="businessDeal.php?recordID=87" target="_blank" >View Details</a>
         </div>
         <!-- LINK GENERATED BASED ON ADDRESS -->
         <a href="map.php?recordID=27" target="_blank"><img src="images/mapIt.png" alt="Map It" class="mapImg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="deal">
         <a href="businessProfile.php?recordID=71" title="logo"><img src="_logos/2865517138.jpg" alt="Business Logo" class="businessLogo" /></a>
         <div class="businessContactInfo">
            <!-- LINK TO BUSINESS PROFILE -->   
            <h4><a href="businessProfile.php?recordID=71">Small Emperor</a></h4>
            <ul>
               <li class="ChamberTitle-A">Chamber Member</li>
               <li>(480) 586-1800</li>
               <li>2702 N GREENFIELD RD</li>
               <li>Any Town, Arizona 85006</li>
               <li><a href="http://www.smallemperor.com" target="_blank">www.smallemperor.com</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="dealDescription">
            <p>super fridays!!</p>
            <a href="businessDeal.php?recordID=132" target="_blank" >View Details</a>
         </div>
         <!-- LINK GENERATED BASED ON ADDRESS -->
         <a href="map.php?recordID=71" target="_blank"><img src="images/mapIt.png" alt="Map It" class="mapImg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="deal">
         <a href="businessProfile.php?recordID=71" title="logo"><img src="_logos/2865517138.jpg" alt="Business Logo" class="businessLogo" /></a>
         <div class="businessContactInfo">
            <!-- LINK TO BUSINESS PROFILE -->   
            <h4><a href="businessProfile.php?recordID=71">Small Emperor</a></h4>
            <ul>
               <li class="ChamberTitle-A">Chamber Member</li>
               <li>(480) 586-1800</li>
               <li>2702 N GREENFIELD RD</li>
               <li>Any Town, Arizona 85006</li>
               <li><a href="http://www.smallemperor.com" target="_blank">www.smallemperor.com</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="dealDescription">
            <p> Expert Web Design from Lindsey</p>
            <a href="businessDeal.php?recordID=133" target="_blank" >View Details</a>
         </div>
         <!-- LINK GENERATED BASED ON ADDRESS -->
         <a href="map.php?recordID=71" target="_blank"><img src="images/mapIt.png" alt="Map It" class="mapImg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="deal">
         <a href="businessProfile.php?recordID=71" title="logo"><img src="_logos/2865517138.jpg" alt="Business Logo" class="businessLogo" /></a>
         <div class="businessContactInfo">
            <!-- LINK TO BUSINESS PROFILE -->   
            <h4><a href="businessProfile.php?recordID=71">Small Emperor</a></h4>
            <ul>
               <li class="ChamberTitle-A">Chamber Member</li>
               <li>(480) 586-1800</li>
               <li>2702 N GREENFIELD RD</li>
               <li>Any Town, Arizona 85006</li>
               <li><a href="http://www.smallemperor.com" target="_blank">www.smallemperor.com</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="dealDescription">
            <p> Expert Web Design from Lindsey</p>
            <a href="businessDeal.php?recordID=134" target="_blank" >View Details</a>
         </div>
         <!-- LINK GENERATED BASED ON ADDRESS -->
         <a href="map.php?recordID=71" target="_blank"><img src="images/mapIt.png" alt="Map It" class="mapImg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="deal">
         <a href="businessProfile.php?recordID=26" title="logo"><img src="_logos/Bobs_logo.gif" alt="Business Logo" class="businessLogo" /></a>
         <div class="businessContactInfo">
            <!-- LINK TO BUSINESS PROFILE -->   
            <h4><a href="businessProfile.php?recordID=26">Bob's Market</a></h4>
            <ul>
               <li class="ChamberTitle-A">Chamber Member</li>
               <li>(623) 222-3333</li>
               <li>12145 NW Grand Ave</li>
               <li>Any Town, Arizona 85335</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="dealDescription">
            <p>$2 Freshly Baked Loaf of Bread</p>
            <a href="businessDeal.php?recordID=89" target="_blank" >View Details</a>
         </div>
         <!-- LINK GENERATED BASED ON ADDRESS -->
         <a href="map.php?recordID=26" target="_blank"><img src="images/mapIt.png" alt="Map It" class="mapImg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="deal">
         <a href="businessProfile.php?recordID=28" title="logo"><img src="_logos/1418244938.jpg" alt="Business Logo" class="businessLogo" /></a>
         <div class="businessContactInfo">
            <!-- LINK TO BUSINESS PROFILE -->   
            <h4><a href="businessProfile.php?recordID=28">The Hat Store</a></h4>
            <ul>
               <li>(623) 999-3333</li>
               <li>12145 NW Grand Ave</li>
               <li>Any Town, Arizona 85335</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="dealDescription">
            <p>All Green Hats 50% Off!</p>
            <a href="businessDeal.php?recordID=64" target="_blank" >View Details</a>
         </div>
         <!-- LINK GENERATED BASED ON ADDRESS -->
         <a href="map.php?recordID=28" target="_blank"><img src="images/mapIt.png" alt="Map It" class="mapImg" /></a>
      </div>
      <br class="clear" />
   </div>
   <!-- GENERATE PRINTABLE ADS -->
   <div id="printAds">
      <a href="deals.php" target="_blank">Print Shop Local Weekly</a>
   </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section#homeDealsList div#dealsContent div.deal {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #222222;
}
section#homeDealsList div#dealsContent div.deal:last-child {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle with the full code? It helps to be able to tweak it.

Comment: A fiddle, or a snippet right here is useful too.

Comment: Find a detailed explanation of the problems, their cause and solution below, along with some insight into where this all came from.

Comment: The chosen answer again shows that most of the time new users just come to SO to get solutions, not explanations. Sad story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Fix for expanding text**

Clear your floats,

```
.deal:after {
   content: " ";
   clear: both;
   display: block;
}
```

I think that should work. Should be usable on most modern browsers, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent for support.

**2. Removing the bottom border on last** `<div>`

Delete the `<br>` line break after the last `<div`> that has class `.deal` assigned to it.

Answer (score 2):

## 2 problems to be solved

### #1 `:last-child` "*doesn't work*"

The last child in your `div#dealsContent` is `<br class="clear">`, not a `div.deal`, so the selector finds no corresponding element that matches `section#homeDealsList div#dealsContent div.deal:last-child`. You are using unnecessary markup to clear your float. The best practice way to achieve the clearing is by applying a so-called `clearfix`. Find more information on it here (the article is from 2005, but clearly helps you develop a good understanding of the topic):

> http://www.sitepoint.com/simple-clearing-of-floats/

If you're interested in a bit of webdesign history, this is where it all came from (at the time the most influential site on frontend related topics, together with [alistapart.com](http://alistapart.com)):

> http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

### #2 Content inside `div.deal` grows 'out of' its container

You need to understand that floated elements inside a container are not relevant in any way when it comes to calculating the parent element's height. Without any additional style a container that has only floating children will always have a *height of 0*. This is exactly the type of situation where `clearfix` helps and what it's original purpose was: To make sure a container expands so that it fully ***contains*** its floating child elements.

So, to solve both problems at once, simply remove

```
<br class="clear">
```

and introduce a new rule in your css:

```
.deal:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
}
```

### Mission accomplished!

This creates a hidden pseudo element in your page `:after` every `div.deal`, without any additional, unnecessary markup, and this pseudo element does the clearfix "magic" (which in fact it isn't) for you.

Answer (score 1):

To clear floats:

```
.deal:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

To remove the bottom border:

```
.deal:last-child { border-bottom: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

For removing the extra border in the bottom section, it is not caused by last-child, it is caused by the entire section/table.

Delete the line or target .clear for removing border

```
<br class="clear">
```

You need to set a height for each item for the overflow problem.

```
.deal {
  height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html put:

```
<style>
section#homeDealsList div#dealsContent div.deal {
    width:100%;
    padding:30px 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #222222;
}

section#homeDealsList div#dealsContent div.deal:last-child {
    border:none;
}

</style>
```

Comment: What is this supposed to achieve? Repeating rules that don't get applied will ***not*** raise your chances here... HTML is not a dog that might listen the third time you repeat your command ;)